# как организовать проверку вводимого текста в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, text

Как можно организовать ввод только цифр в текстовое поле, или же наоборот, ввод только буквенных символов. Искал в интернете, вменяемых решений не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть очень простое решение - вешать лисенер на изменение текста и смотреть по регулярному выражание, что оно подходит.

```
 String numberMatcher = "^-?\\d+$";
                                   //t1 - новый текст, s - старый текст.
 textBox.textProperty().addListener((observableValue, s, t1) - > {
     if (!t1.isEmpty()) {
         if (!t1.matches(numberMatcher)) {
             textBox.setText(s);
         } else {
             try {
                 // тут можете парсить строку как захотите
                 int value = Integer.parseInt(t1);
                 textBox.setText(value);
             } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                 this.setText(s);
             }
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: распишите пожалуйста что значит "^-?\\d+$"

Comment: Почитайте про регулярные выражения. А данная строка значит что можно вводить как положительные числа так и отрицательные.

Answer (score 1):

Я создавал класс, расширяющий TextField и переопределял replaceText

```
@Override
public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
    if (!"1234567890.\b".contains(text)){text = "";}
}
```